# Integral of product of Bessel functions of first kind

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I am interested in the integral
$$I(t,s)=\int_0^1 \frac{J_0(tx)J_1(t(x+s)) }{x+s}\mathrm{d}x$$
for $t,s\ge 0$.

I found that for $s=0$ there is a closed expression
$$I(t,0)=t J_0(t){}^2-J_1(t) J_0(t)+t J_1(t)^2$$
but I am wondering whether for $s>0$ there might be something similar?

Comment: Closest things I could find were identities 10.22... on [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22) but they still don't quite match.